# Apps always autoreload

Tags: bugs

I bought my Nexus 6P in Canada. Occasionally, I travel to China. Then this weird issue starts happening: for every app, the top activity refreshes itself periodically. For example, when I am reading Quora, the app refreshes itself while I am reading, causing the scrollback moved back to the very top. It is almost like Activty.onCreate() is invoked periodically by a scheduler. This issue happens to both Google Play installed apps and 3rd party apps. However, when I return to Canada, everything is automatically fixed.

What is the cause of the issue, and how do I fix it?

Also, having a VPN that unblocks Google Service does not help.